# Given a set of vectors how to pick $M$ such that sum of maximums of coordinates is maximized?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, oc.optimization-and-control, numerical-linear-algebra

I asked the same on [math.Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4520055/721298).

I have $n$ (say $n = 300$) vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$.  Each of them has $K$ coordinates (say $K = 30$). For vector $v_j$ I denote it's coordinates as $v_{j1},\dots,v_{jK}$. I want select $M$ (say $M = 5$) vectors ${v_{\hat s_1}}, \dots, v_{\hat s_M} \in \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ such that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{K}\max_{1 \le m \le M} v_{\hat s_mk} = \max_{1 \le s_1 \le n,\dots, \le s_m \le n}\sum_{k=1}^{K}\max_{1 \le m \le M} v_{s_mk}.$$
What's the name for this type of questions? How do I (approximately) solve those fast? (I need to solve like 30 per minute)

Comment: What is known about the coordinates? Are they integer? How large?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev In my application (or more precisely in a toy version of my application) they are real. But integers are fine too or even $\{0, 1\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At very least the problem can be approached via (M)ILP by introducing indicator variables $q_{jk}$ telling whether the corresponding coordinate $v_{jk}$ is present in the sum of max, and $r_j$ telling whether the vector $v_j$ is selected. This results in the following formulation:

$$\begin{cases}
\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^K v_{jk} q_{jk} \longrightarrow \max\\
\sum_{j=1}^n q_{jk} = 1\qquad (k\in[K]), \\
\sum_{k=1}^K q_{jk} \leq Kr_j\qquad (j\in[n]), \\
\sum_{j=1}^n r_j = M, \\
q_{jk}, r_j\in\{0,1\}\qquad (j\in[n],\ k\in[K]).
\end{cases}$$